# Best way to encode tuples with json

Tags: python, json

In python I have a dictionary that maps tuples to a list of tuples. e.g.

`{(1,2): [(2,3),(1,7)]}`

I want to be able to encode this data use it with javascript, so I looked into json but it appears keys must be strings so my tuple does not work as a key.

Is the best way to handle this is encode it as "1,2" and then parse it into something I want on the javascript? Or is there a more clever way to handle this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You might consider saying

```
{"[1,2]": [(2,3),(1,7)]}
```

and then when you need to get the value out, you can just parse the keys themselves as JSON objects, which all modern browsers can do with the built-in `JSON.parse` method (I'm using `jQuery.each` to iterate here but you could use anything):

```
var myjson = JSON.parse('{"[1,2]": [[2,3],[1,7]]}');
$.each(myjson, function(keystr,val){
    var key = JSON.parse(keystr);
    // do something with key and val
});
```

On the other hand, you might want to just structure your object differently, e.g.

```
{1: {2: [(2,3),(1,7)]}}
```

so that instead of saying

```
myjson[1,2] // doesn't work
```

which is invalid Javascript syntax, you could say

```
myjson[1][2] // returns [[2,3],[1,7]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of nested dictionaries! I wouldn't have thought of that. Not sure which approach will work better for me but seems like a neat idea, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

If your key tuples are truly integer pairs, then the easiest and probably most straightforward approach would be as you suggest....  encode them to a string. You can do this in a one-liner:

```
>>> simplejson.dumps(dict([("%d,%d" % k, v) for k, v in d.items()]))
'{"1,2": [[2, 3], [1, 7]]}'
```

This would get you a javascript data structure whose keys you could then split to get the points back again:

```
'1,2'.split(',')
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit nosklo... everyone needs a good editor :-)

Comment: For this specific example, tuple('1,2'.split(',')).  And if the question's example is The Norm, one'd want tuple(int(s) for s in '1,2'.split(','))).

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be:

```
{ "1": [
        { "2": [[2,3],[1,7]] }
       ]
}
```

It's still parsing, but depending on how you use it, it may be easier in this form.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an array as a key in JSON. The best you can do is encode it. Sorry, but there's really no other sane way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Could it simply be a two dimensional array? Then you may use integers as keys

Comment: two dimensional arrays are clumsy in python, otherwise that may work.