# Saving dictionary whose keys are tuples with json, python

Tags: python, json, tuples

I am writing a little program in python and I am using a dictionary whose (like the title says) keys and values are tuples. I am trying to use json as follows

```
import json
data = {(1,2,3):(a,b,c),(2,6,3):(6,3,2)}
print json.dumps(data)
```

Problem is I keep getting `TypeError: keys must be a string`.

How can I go about doing it? I tried looking at the python documentation but didn't see any clear solution. Thanks!

Comment: But the JSON format requires keys to be strings...

Comment: Can I parse it as a String then?

Comment: Why do you need tuples as keys?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to encode tuples with json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715550/best-way-to-encode-tuples-with-json)

Answer (score 18):

You'll need to convert your tuples to strings first:

```
json.dumps({str(k): v for k, v in data.iteritems()})
```

Of course, you'll end up with strings instead of tuples for keys:

```
'{"(1, 2, 3)": ["a", "b", "c"], "(2, 6, 3)": [6, 3, 2]}'
```

Comment: It would be interesting to know how to reverse this action.

Comment: @RickyRobinson: `ast.literal_eval()` will reconstitute the Python value from the string.

Comment: This worked for me in python3: converted={ast.literal_eval(k): v for k, v in json.items()}

Answer (score 7):

If you want to load your data later on you have to postprocess it anyway. Therefore I'd just dump `data.items()`:

```
>>> import json
>>> a, b, c = "abc"
>>> data = {(1,2,3):(a,b,c), (2,6,3):(6,3,2)}
>>> on_disk = json.dumps(data.items())
>>> on_disk
'[[[2, 6, 3], [6, 3, 2]], [[1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]]]'
>>> data_restored = dict(map(tuple, kv) for kv in json.loads(on_disk))
>>> data_restored
{(2, 6, 3): (6, 3, 2), (1, 2, 3): (u'a', u'b', u'c')}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ujson module. ujson.dumps() accepts tuples as keys in a dictionary.
You can install ujson by pip.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3* users:
in addition to @Martijn Pieters answer,

`dictonary.iteritems()` is not valid, replace it with `dictionary.items()` :

```
json.dumps({str(k): v for k, v in data.items()})
```